# AngularJS - Load image to img tag on file input

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a img tag and an input file looking the like this:

```
<img ng-src="{{item.showImage || '//:0'}}"  />
<input type="file" accept="image/*" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().getImage(this.files)"/>
```

on the controller I have the following function:

```
$scope.getImage = function(files){
     $scope.item.image = files[0];
     var reader = new FileReader();
     reader.onload = function(e){
           $scope.item.showImage = e.target.result;
     }
     reader.readAdDataURL($scope.item.image);
}
```

My purpose is to show the image selected by the user in the img tag using ng-src,
this works only when I call $scope.$apply(), I wonder if there's a way to make it work without calling it?

Comment: no, see this issue: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1375

Comment: @squiroid this is not a duplicate as i know how to catch the chnages, just wondering how to make the new file selected show in the ng-src

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/DNq3NJj3x5SNvvx4xYv5?p=preview). You can use a directive for the image field that will watch for changes and will also return the image in a way that the template will be able to display it.

```
var UploadController = function ($scope, fileReader) {
    $scope.getFile = function () {

        fileReader.readAsDataUrl($scope.file, $scope)
            .then(function(result) {
                $scope.imageSrc = result;
            });
    };
};

app.directive("ngFileSelect",function(){
  return {
    link: function($scope,el){

      el.bind("change", function(e){

        $scope.file = (e.srcElement || e.target).files[0];
        $scope.getFile();
      })
    }
  }
});
```

Then you will also need that as a service:

```
(function (module) {

    var fileReader = function ($q, $log) {

        var onLoad = function(reader, deferred, scope) {
            return function () {
                scope.$apply(function () {
                    deferred.resolve(reader.result);
                });
            };
        };

        var getReader = function(deferred, scope) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onerror = onError(reader, deferred, scope);
            return reader;
        };

        var readAsDataURL = function (file, scope) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();

            var reader = getReader(deferred, scope);         
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);

            return deferred.promise;
        };

        return {
            readAsDataUrl: readAsDataURL  
        };
    };

    module.factory("fileReader",
                   ["$q", "$log", fileReader]);

}(angular.module("plunker")));
```

Comment: That's a great solution but still uses $scope.$apply, i was looking for something that doesn't require me to do that.